# Get all objects not in M2M table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
```

How would I get all `order_items` that are not in an invoice?

It would be like:

```
OrderItem.objects.exclude(id__in=invoice) # pseudocode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
ordered_items_not_in_invoice = OrderItem.objects.filter(invoice__isnull=True)
```

Read more on [Lookups spanning multi valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) and [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)